# Show non-nested div on hover and hide after delay

Tags: jquery, mouseover, show-hide

I am trying to show div #2 when div #1 is moused-over. If div #2 isn't moused-over within a short period of time (say 3 seconds) then it hides. I have got the code semi-working but it acts really buggy. Sometimes it doesn't hide at all and I can't figure out how to adjust the time before it hides again.

```
<div id="1">When this is moused-over</div>
<div id="2">Show this and then hide again if not moused-over within 3 secs.</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t0hj0r52/

**EDIT:** In case anyone needs it in the future. I've fixed the code and added in some to keep the div open after it has been moused over. Before, if you moused over div #1 and accidentally moused over div #2 when navigating away, div #2 would immediately disappear.

http://jsfiddle.net/t0hj0r52/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code is good you only are not used the same div class you are trying to hide, in your code I see a $(menu).hide and there is no menu var declared.
change to:

```
intVal=  setTimeout(function() { $('.email-div').hide(); }, 3000);
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. I've updated it. http://jsfiddle.net/t0hj0r52/1/

Comment: Any suggestions on getting it to stay when the user clicks into it? Say I have a form and they are trying to fill it out but their mouse drops off the div after they click into the input field?

Comment: Is the same you already did with the mouseenter event you called  clearTimeout(intVal); this way if I stay on div2 it never disappear. You can call the same on click function. If you want that when click your div never dissapear anymore you can remove the event listener of mouseleave like this: $('.email-div').click(function(e) {
          $(this).off('mouseleave');
       });